# mock HTTP POST request

Tags: python, unit-testing, post, selenium, mocking

I have a python FLASK view with only POST method implementation. I do not need a GET because an external template would POST data to this view. 
Now i want to write unit test for this view, where in I want to mock the initial POST request and assert that the view implementation works properly.

Example of external template which will access my view implementation:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
     <TITLE> New Document </TITLE>
     <META NAME="Author" CONTENT="Richard Ward">
     <META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="">
     <META NAME="Description" CONTENT="Test Page">
    </HEAD>

    <BODY>
        <FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="www.myView.com/testview">
         <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="employeeId" value="304253498022">
         <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="employeeName" value="testName">
         <INPUT TYPE="submit" name="submit" value="Show Information">
        </FORM>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

My view class

```
class TestView(MethodView):
    app = None
    def post(self):
        """
        Implementation of the post request for this view
        """
        employeeId= request.form.get('employeeId', None)
        employeeName = request.form.get('employeeName', None)

        # some data processing code

        return render_template("summary.html")

    @classmethod
    def registerSelf(cls, app):
        """
        Registers itself as a view with the passed Flask application
        """
        TestView.app = app
        app.flaskApp.add_url_rule('/testview', view_func=TestView.as_view('testview'))
```

I want to directly call the post of my view and pass mock form data in the body of the request

Comment: do you need to use selenium or can you use flasks built in test client? http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/testing/, http://stackoverflow.com/a/15838404/594589

Comment: would using the flask built in test client make it easier to mock POST request?

Comment: Yes, that is what the test client is designed to do

Comment: @dm03514 thanks for your suggestion, but i will not be able to use test client, because the way my application is designed i will have to deploy the whole thing for it to function properly for testing.Therefore i need to somehow write a selenium test which would mock POST request

Comment: what do you mean by "deploy the whole thing for it to function properly for testing"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just stuck on this for 2 hours and it turns out you can just pass a dictionary as your data payload in your test, and you will be able to access it from your code via `request.form.get`

Example test code

```
from <the module you want to test> import app
    app.testing = True
    self.app = app.test_client()
    self.app.post(<endpoint name, for example /index>, data={
        'employeeId': '1',
        'employeeName': 'Ruth'})
```